# C# создание своего типа данных

Tags: c#

Мне нужен свой тип данных, размер которого будет очень мал - 4 бит. Как это реализовать? Нужно это для более компактного хранения в памяти и на HDD чисел от 0 до 31. Использовать, например, Byte, чтобы в его двоичном коде хранить 2 моих переменных не вариант, т.к. мне нужны массивы с 4ех байтным типом данных

Comment: Спасибо! Это очень хорошая альтернатива. Но нельзя ли в C# "создать" свой тип данных? Чтобы так же его инициализировать, как и int, long, short и т.д. ?

Comment: Свой тип (класс, структуру) создать можно. Примитив, наподобие int, long - нет. Минимальным адресуемым элементом является байт, так что по-любому придётся основываться на нём.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, есть еще [BitArray](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=netframework-4.7.1) и [BitVector32](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32?view=netframework-4.7.1) правда не уверен на сколько они тут применимы

Comment: для _чисел от 0 до 31_ 4х бит будет маловато

Comment: *мне нужны массивы с 4ех байтным типом данных* -- чем не устраивает штатный Int (он же _int32) ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для хранения чисел от 0 до 31 вам нужно 5 бит. Хранить можно в `BitArray` (но по факту, будет выделено все равно 1 байт):

```
BitArray thirtyOne  = new BitArray(new[] { true, true, true, true, true}); //число 31
```

Увы, вы не сможете создать тип, который будет занимать меньше 1 байта.

Comment: Как reference-тип, да ещё и с массивом внутри, он будет занимать в десятки раз больше байта.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу вашего вопроса, меня он тоже заинтересовал, конечно все упирается в минимальное значение CLR (byte) - там еще просто стандарт SizeOf (какой-то там ISO). Но мне почему-то стало интересно, ведь есть тип данных bool, который в свою очередь просто триггер (0/1). Который по смыслу должен занимать именно 1 бит. Окей, он приводиться к byte пускай, это приведение примерно так выглядит - true = 0xFF, false = 0x0 - тут тоже действует какой-то там стандарт. Но самое интересно как оказывается начинается, с момента компиляции и интересных аттрибутов для структуры.

В свою очередь я смог нагуглить интересную статью, которая дает намного больше информации по данной теме: https://habr.com/ru/post/114953/
Так как мои знания и мое осознание данной проблемы, немного не литературным языком сформированы, то и галантно описать я не могу (почитайте статью). Ко всему прочему, еще на cyberforum'e (http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread341534.html), есть интересный эксперимент-обсуждение по этому поводу.

Answer (score -1):

На основе этого примера верните нужную вам часть масива (Хоть половину значения)

```
List<Byte> List { set; get; } = default;
    public MyType this[int i] {
       get {
         return List[i];
    }
}
```